# How to deploy a React App on Apache web server

Tags: javascript, apache, reactjs

I have created a basic React App from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_jsx.htm here , I want to run this test code on Apache based server, I know that I need to create a distributable build but I am not able to figure out how to do that and couldnt find clear instructions.

I have seen this post [React,js on Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045747/react-js-on-apache-server) but it doesn't have anything more than few guidelines

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ultimately was able to figure it out , i just hope it will help someone like me.
Following is how the web pack config file should look like 
check the dist dir and output file specified. I was missing the way to specify the path of dist directory

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    },

    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}

module.exports = config;
```

Then the package json file

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --progress",
    "production": "webpack -p --progress"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "webpack": "^1.9.6",
    "webpack-devserver": "0.0.6"
  }
}
```

Notice the script section and production section, production section is what gives you the final deployable index.js file ( name can be anything )

Rest fot the things will depend upon your code and components

Execute following sequence of commands

> npm install

this should get you all the dependency (node modules)

then

> npm run production

this should get you the final `index.js` file which will contain all the code bundled

Once done place `index.html` and `index.js` files under www/html or the web app root directory and that's all.

Comment: Also it's better to launch app on process manager, like pm2 library. It provides automatic rerun app after crashing or server restart.

Answer (score 62):

Firstly, in your react project go to your **package.json** file and adjust this line of code to match your destination domain address + folder:

```
"homepage": "https://yourwebsite.com/your_folder_name/",
```

Secondly, go to **terminal** in your react project and type:

```
npm run build
```

Now, **take all files** from that newly created **build** folder and upload them into
**your_folder_name**, with filezilla in subfolder like this:

```
public_html/your_folder_name
```

Check in the browser!

Comment: that works, I just made mistake, when on localhost, give it path like "homepage": "http://localhost/yourapp/build" or move your build directory to URL path you have given

Comment: My package.json did not have homepage field. Once I added manually, the procedure worked as expected.

Comment: Does this work with React Router?

Comment: This kind of work for me!  I too didn't find a homepage field.  I didn't add it and that seems to okay.  I ran into another problem though.  The index.html page in the build folder had tags with the "href" attribute pointing to paths that began with a "/".  I had to delete that "/" character all those paths and  then the app work from my apache server.  At this time I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do the "npm run build" so it makes relative paths instead or if I have to do some configuration in Apache server to set the app root directory correctly.

Comment: Okay I now see what's going on.  I do need to add the homepage field but I needed to set it to:   "homepage": "./",   see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235798/relative-path-in-index-html-after-build for more information

Answer (score 37):

1. Go to your project root directory, e.g.: `cd /home/ubuntu/react-js`.
2. Build your project first: `npm run build`.
3. Check your build directory, all of the following files will be available in the build folder:

```
   asset-manifest.json
   favicon.ico
   manifest.json
   robots.txt
   static 
   assets
   index.html
   precache-manifest.ddafca92870314adfea99542e1331500.js 
   service-worker.js
```

4. Copy the build folder to your apache server i.e `/var/www/html`:

   `sudo cp -rf build /var/www/html`
5. Go to sites-available directory:

   `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/`
6. Open the `000-default.conf` file:

`sudo vi 000-default.conf` and rechange the DocumentRoot path to `/var/www/html/build`.

[image: Screenshot of the correct DocumentRoot setting]

7. Now go to the Apache configuration.

`cd /etc/apache2`

`sudo vi apache2.conf`

Add the following snippet:

```html
<Directory /var/www/html>

       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

       AllowOverride All

       Require all granted

</Directory>
```

8. Make a file inside `/var/www/html/build`:

   `sudo vi .htaccess`

```html
Options -MultiViews
    
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

9. Restart Apache server:

   `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: You saved me man! My entire day ruined for this, now i can sleep! :)

Comment: Do you need to always create new `.htaccess` when you create new build?

Comment: Could you comment what's the point of step 7?

Comment: `RewriteEngine` requires the `rewrite` module to be enabled with `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: totally working fine for me.. thank you so much for the detailed answer.. 

Answer (score 18):

Before making the npm build, 
1) Go to your React project root folder and open `package.json`. 
2) Add "homepage" attribute to `package.json`

- if you want to provide **absolute** path

  ```
  "homepage": "http://hostName.com/appLocation",
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  ```
- if you want to provide **relative** path

  ```
  "homepage": "./",
  "name": "react-app",
  ```

  Using relative path method may warn a syntax validation error in your IDE. But the build is made without any errors during compilation.

3) Save the `package.json` , and in terminal run `npm run-script build`
4) Copy the contents of `build/` folder to your server directory.

PS: It is easy to use relative path method if you want to change the build file location in your server frequently.

Comment: When using "nwb", "homepage" seems to be ignored and "webpack.publicPath" is used instead, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441825

Answer (score 7):

As said in the post, React is a browser based technology. It only renders a view in an HTML document.

To be able to have access to your "React App", you need to:

1. Bundle your React app in a bundle
2. Have Apache pointing to your html file in your server, and allowing access externally.

You might have all the informations here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/getting-started.html for the Apache server, and here to make your javascript bundle https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr

Comment: I know how to make Apache work, i am a PHP dev, my problem is I am stuck with building the distributable out of source and then setting up apache for redirection

Comment: I see. You want to build the javascript library then, using a module bundler (e.g. webpack). https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr. I have also edited my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: Will the route to other pages work directly in the URL Bar?

Answer (score 4):

You can run it through the Apache proxy, but it would have to be running in a virtual directory (e.g. http://mysite.something/myreactapp ).

This may seem sort of redundant but if you have other pages that are not part of your React app (e.g. PHP pages), you can serve everything via port 80 and make it apear that the whole thing is a cohesive website.

1.) Start your react app with npm run, or whatever command you are using to start the node server. Assuming it is running on http://127.0.0.1:8080

2.) Edit httpd-proxy.conf and add:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  </Proxy>

ProxyPass /myreactapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /myreactapp  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

3.) Restart Apache

Comment: This was about production , I don't want such setup i production

Answer (score 2):

As well described in React's official [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/), If you use routers that use the HTML5 `pushState` history API under the hood, you just need to add below content to `.htaccess` file in `public` directory of your react-app.

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

And if using relative path update the `package.json` like this:

```
"homepage": ".",
```

**Note**: If you are using `react-router@^4`, you can root `<Link>` using the `basename` prop on any `<Router>`.

```
import React from 'react';
import BrowserRouter as Router from 'react-router-dom';
...
<Router basename="/calendar"/>
<Link to="/today"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add a pom.xml and make it a maven project and then build it. It will create a War file for you in the target folder after that you can deploy it wherever you want.

pom.xml
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    4.0.0
    it.megadix
    create-react-app-servlet
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <npm.output.directory>build</npm.output.directory>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Standard plugin to generate WAR -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${npm.output.directory}</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <webXml>${basedir}/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Required: The following will ensure `npm install` is called
                     before anything else during the 'Default Lifecycle' -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install (initialize)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Required: The following will ensure `npm install` is called
                     before anything else during the 'Clean Lifecycle' -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install (clean)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- Required: This following calls `npm run build` where 'build' is
                     the script name I used in my project, change this if yours is
                         different -->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build (compile)</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>run</argument>
                            <argument>build</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <CI>true</CI>
                    <!-- The following parameters create an NPM sandbox for CI -->
                    <NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX>${basedir}/npm</NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX>
                    <NPM_CONFIG_CACHE>${NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX}/cache</NPM_CONFIG_CACHE>
                    <NPM_CONFIG_TMP>${project.build.directory}/npmtmp</NPM_CONFIG_TMP>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <PUBLIC_URL>http://localhost:8080/${project.artifactId}</PUBLIC_URL>
                            <REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>/${project.artifactId}</REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <PUBLIC_URL>http://my-awesome-production-host/${project.artifactId}</PUBLIC_URL>
                            <REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>/${project.artifactId}</REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE>
                        </environmentVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Note:- If you find a blank page after running your project then clear your cache or restart your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

First install `apache2` with `sudo apt install apache2` then run commend blow in proj dir

```
npm run build
```

or

```
yarn run build
```

then

```
sudo cp -rf build/* /var/www/html/mySite;
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/;
sudo cp 000-default.conf mySite.conf;
sudo nano /mySite.conf
```

in this file add/uncomment these lines

```
ServerName myDomin.com
ServerAlias www.myDomin.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mySite
```

after appache configurations you should add your domin to your system so

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

in this file add your VPS IP address for example if your ip address is `192.168.1.1` so

```
127.0.0.1       localhost myDomin.com
192.168.1.1       myDomin.com www.myDomin.com
```

now set your name servers in your VPS by your own if [you know how](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/dns/how-to-point-domain-to-vps) or just use cloudflare or similar things.

> note: If you want use in localhost just run this `cp build/* /var/www/html/ && sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to add proxy in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` directory, then execute `sudo nano your-domain.conf`, and add proxy, and then run with `pm2 restart all`.