# Relative path in index.html after build

Tags: reactjs, build, path, create-react-app, react-scripts

Hello i have a reactjs app, and I build my project with bellow command

```
npm build
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"},
```

after build i have folder with build files and index.html file
But all paths in this .html are absolute, i want to build with relative path

for example (index.html):
now i have:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.af2bdfd5.js"></script>
> <link href="/static/css/main.097da2df.css" rel="stylesheet">
> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
> ```

i want this:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.af2bdfd5.js"></script>
> <link href="./static/css/main.097da2df.css" rel="stylesheet">
> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
> ```

Comment: Try to use html-webpack-plugin, it is uniquely need you to deploy in the future.

Answer (score 272):

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "your-project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "./", # <--- Add this line ----
  ...
}
```

Run `npm run build` again.

This will change the path to `./`, which is the relative path of your project.

Comment: also official documentation covers [this topic](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths)

Comment: The documentation has been updated to suggest using `"."` and not `"./"`. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1487#issuecomment-277727669)

Comment: When I use "." or "./" I can see that all the paths now have a dot at the beginning, but it seems that browsers ignore that dot and still try to pull from the root. I don't get why react build doesn't just remove the opening forward slash?

Comment: Adding the dot breaks the assets paths for me

Comment: Super helpful.  So difficult to find.  I'm using Photino.io building React JS to create UI for .NET cross-platform apps & the package.json was not using this so it couldn't find resources in proper directory.  This fixed it perfectly.

Comment: I would give you a hug right now - saved my evening. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

I encountered a similar issue and resolved it by setting `"homepage": "./"` in package.json

I found this solution here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/165

Comment: It seems that this fix is specific to projects created by create-react-app?

Comment: Weird, this should be the default results? from the number of votes, it seems the current default is unexpected or not natural choice.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using Vite as my build engine instead of CRA. It does not appear to look at the `homepage` option in package.json at all. Instead to fix this issue I added a new build option in my scripts that sets the base URL like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "production": "tsc && vite build --base=./"
}
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path). Hope this helps someone.
*I know this does not answer OP's question but someone with the same issue might stumble on this like I did*

Comment: You're a legend!

Comment: Anyone using Vite should upvote this answer. None of the other methods works or even makes sense :)

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't have been this hard to find!

Answer (score 8):

If you're using webpack, you can try setting `publicPath` to `./`

You can read more about it [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, React's documentation covers this topic:

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths

Facebook recommends to install the tool env-cmd, create a file with an environment variable and a script in package.json to run.

That's a good concept but unfortunately, this fix does not work properly for two reasons.

First, env-cmd requires the path to start with `./`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...,
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f ./.env.staging yarn run build"
}
```

Second, I'm not sure what the environment variable `REACT_APP_API_URL` is being used for but at least in create-react-app it's `PUBLIC_URL`. Creating a file named `.env.staging` with the following content solved the issue for me:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/projects/my-project
```

I think the creators of build tools should make it easier to deploy to a subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

if your app is directly build in react then set `homepage` as "./" or "" empty string in package.json

and if your site build in child react js then for me it was nextjs so i set "basePath" in next.config.js as "" empty string and my issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above did not work for me. My solution was the following:

1. Ensure that a base URL is set in the `index.hmtl`:

```
<base url="%PUBLIC_URL%" />
```

2. Do not set `homepage` in the `package.json`.
3. In `.env`, set `PUBLIC_URL` equal to the path at which you want to serve the app. This should not include the domain so that the build can be deployed to multiple environments (dev, prod etc.)
4. In any ingress configuration, use the same path as `PUBLIC_URL`.