# Electron loads index.html but not the rest of the bundle files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

We have an electron app and want to load the renderer bundle using `loadUrl()`.

```js
win=new BrowserWindow({ /* ... */ })
win.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname, '../../render/build/index.html')}`);
```

Inside the html file, we load the React Bundle

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app-my-hash.bundle.js"></script>
```

However, as expected, the file is not found, since, I guess, I need to set the root of the project somehow. I get this error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

What setting am I missing on the electron side (or webpack side) to get this working?

Comment: Which file is not found? If index.html, does it load if you use absolute address instead of path.join? Or app-my-hash.bundle.js ? If yes, Is it in root js folder? Did you try to load it with require('myfile.js')?

Comment: The JS is missing. It is not in root js. It is in a js folder that is relative to the index.html. I did not try to load it with require, it is bundled by webpack.

Comment: Try relative URL, like: `src="js/app-my-hash.bundle.js"` or `src="./js/app-my-hash.bundle.js"`

Comment: Yup. That worked.

Comment: Great. I put it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative URL, like: `src="js/app-my-hash.bundle.js"` or `src="./js/app-my-hash.bundle.js"`

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to add relative path without manual update in **index.html** is by including,

> **homepage** property in **package.json**.

For an example,

```
{
  "name": "electron-project",
  "homepage": "./", # Add this line
  #.... all remaining properties
}
```

[Stackoverflow Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473246/4067157)