# How to run two js apps on different url with Nginx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I want to run two different js apps on my Nginx server. My problem is that I want to enable the React app on the main URL `/` on port 3000 and different js app on port 1337.

When I set React App on the main URL it's working properly but any application on different URL like `/admin` that loads the second app it's not loaded properly. I have changed the paths and now I have my second app on main URL `/` and it's working properly but when I run React app on `/admin` URL it cannot load files properly.

How to connect two js apps on different locations using Nginx?? I am using react-react-app and create-strapi-app. You can check this on IP: http://51.178.80.233/ and client: http://51.178.80.233/client

Working example works without two `root` lines on each location.

My config on `sites-enabled/default`:

```
root /var/www/jozefrzadkosz-portfolio.pl;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location /client {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                #as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                root /var/www/jozefrzadkosz-portfolio.pl/client;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #whatever port your app runs on
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    location / {
        root /var/www/jozefrzadkosz-portfolio.pl/strapi;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

Comment: How about using subdomain? Create a dns A type record with name `client` and point to your IP. create a config file in sites-enabled folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some considerations about proxying application under some URI prefix, for example, `/admin/`.

1. Use correct location prefix and [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) URL parameter. When you use configuration

   ```
   location /admin {
       ...
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }
   ```

   request `http://example.com/admin/some/path` will be passed to upstream as is, i.e. `http://localhost:3000/admin/some/path`, which is probably wrong. If you want this request to be passed to upstream as `http://localhost:3000/some/path`, you must use an URI part when you specify an upstream address:

   ```
   location /admin/ {
       ...
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
   }
   ```

   Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650827) for more details about this behavior.
2. All URLs generated by application (for assets, pages and so on) must be either relative or include `/admin` prefix. Otherwise they wouldn't be processed whithin our location block. This is non-trivial task which depends on application type, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235798/relative-path-in-index-html-after-build) for  react applications (official documentation [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths)). Unfortunaly I know nothing about strapi applications. If you can't affect application URLs generation mechanism, the only way left is to substitute URLs in the response body with the [`ngx_http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) (looks like quite an ugly solution for me).

Comment: These are not two different approaches, these are two necessary conditions :) If all of your apps are working normally than they are already generating proper URLs (probably relative since you do nothing to change them).