# Relative path in index.html after yarn start

Tags: reactjs

My question is similar to the question [Relative path in index.html after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235798/relative-path-in-index-html-after-build), except that it happens in my development environment, and the index.html has:

http://dev.local:8100/app/index.html (in react public folder)

```
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
```

I can make it work if I `build` react, and that's how it work on production. But for development it is better if I can make it work just using `react-scripts start` (yarn/npm).

I have tried changing `homepage` in package.json and `start_url` in manifest.json, but couldn't get it to work.

I need the index.html to be:

```
  <script src="static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js"></script><script src="static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
```

Any suggestions?