# Symfony Encore, does not build index.html file

Tags: node.js, typescript, symfony, webpack-encore

I've been using an open source website to host a domain.
The original github project is using symfony to build the project.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
}
```

I noticed that when deploying to IPFS, the index.html was using absolute pathing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <title></title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/build/images/fav.png" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/main.css">
  <script src="/build/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <img id="logo" src="/build/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />

    <div id="minting-dapp"></div>
  </main>

  <div id="notifications"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I deleted the index.html file and decided to use rebuild the project, but I noticed that encore, does not build the index.html file ever.

I would like my index.html file to update using with the build.

How can I configure it to use the `homepage` variable to use relative pathing similar to how npm build works [see this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473246/19361853)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encore does not build any html files, it generates files for js and css
such as vendor files, runtime, ...

-> [Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)

#### If the html file is a index.html.twig

You can directly specify it in the code :

```
<body>
  <main>
    <img id="logo" src="{{ asset('/images/logo.png')}}" alt="Logo" />

    <div id="minting-dapp"></div>
  </main>

  <div id="notifications"></div>
</body>
```

And then it will not use the absolute path -> Check [Asset Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html)