# How to run create-react-app build version

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have created a test React application and I started it with the *create-react-app*. I am starting it with with *yarn start*, but that starts the debug version of the application. I did *npm run build* and it created the build folder, however when I do *yarn start* from the */build* folder, it still starts the debug version of the application. I need this for testing performance with the optimized version. How can I solve this?

Comment: Any luck with my proposed answer?

Comment: I've updated my answer with resources for running production builds locally using apache, nginx and express.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to move from a development build to a production build with create-react-app you need to deploy it using a web server, I would recommend using [Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration) or a [droplet](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/i-built-this-now-what-how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-a-digitalocean-droplet-662de0fe3f48) or you can use [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/) which has a simple set up procedure using the below commands:

```
cd project-name
npm run build

npm install netlify-cli -g
netlify deploy
```

> Follow command line prompts and choose yes for new project and ./build
>   as your deploy folder and voila you have a production React app!

You can host the app locally using [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461279/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-apache-web-server), [nginx](https://medium.com/@timmykko/deploying-create-react-app-with-nginx-and-ubuntu-e6fe83c5e9e7), [express](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0)

Comment: Is there no way I can run it locally without deploying?

Comment: Yes, if you run a web server locally.

Comment: @gfels Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 12):

You can actually use static server to run build version of your app. It's doable with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). You can test it with:

`npm run build`

`npx serve -s build`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This worked, now to figure out what isnt appearing on my site and why

Answer (score 5):

Navigate inside the directory of your app first.

According to the official [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) website. When you run `npm run build` or `yarn build` you create a `build` directory with a production build of your app.

After running the command above the next thing you can do to check the build version of your app is to install `serve` to serve your static site on the port **5000** by default.

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

This will copy the link to your clipboard that you can paste in your browser and see the build version of your app.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run your app in browser with build files served locally from the filesystem (i.e., without a web server), you can put this in your `package.json`:

```
"homepage": ".",
```

Now

1. build your app with `npm run build`.
2. launch `<your app>/build/index.htm`l in the browser.

**Note**: This solution is not suggested if your app (or some routing library) is using the HTML5 pushState history API. https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing