# How to deploy React with Laravel to my development server

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm so confuse how to setting up my project to deploy my project to my development server. I got a problem after I upload my files to the server.

this is what my browser shows if i open my website url. I read some post in stackoverflow [How to deploy a React App on Apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461279/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-apache-web-server) and tells that I need to npm run build. Yes I tried it but my terminal says

> missing build script

I have question do i need to configure the htaccess? I don't know where to configure in laravel or in react?

**Here's my package.json file**

```
    {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
     "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "eslint": "^4.19.1",
        "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "url-loader": "^1.1.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/recompose": "^0.27.0",
        "antd": "^3.8.2",
        "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.4",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "google-map-react": "^1.1.0",
        "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "jwt-auth": "^2.0.1",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
        "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^4.4.1",
        "react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
        "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^1.2.1",
        "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^1.0.3",
        "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^1.1.1",
        "react-bs-notifier": "^5.0.0",
        "react-filter-search": "^1.0.8",
        "react-geolocated": "^2.4.0",
        "react-geolocation": "^1.0.4",
        "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
        "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
        "react-quill": "^1.3.1",
        "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.10",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-responsive-data-table": "^1.0.4",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-s-alert": "^1.4.1",
        "react-search-input": "^0.11.3",
        "routes": "^2.1.0",
        "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
        "sweetalert-react": "^0.4.11",
        "sweetalert2": "^7.28.4"
    }
}
```

**Here's my webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const package = require('./package.json')

const LIBRARY_NAME = 'fuse'
const VERSION = package.version
const AUTHOR = package.author
const HOMEPAGE = package.homepage

const UglifyJsPlugin = webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin
const env = process.env.WEBPACK_ENV

let copyright = fs.readFileSync('COPYRIGHT.txt', 'UTF8')
let outputFile
let plugins = [
  new webpack.BannerPlugin({
    banner: copyright
      .replace('{VERSION}', `v${VERSION}`)
      .replace('{AUTHOR_URL}', `${AUTHOR.url}`)
      .replace('{HOMEPAGE}', `${HOMEPAGE}`),
    entryOnly: true
  })
]

if (env === 'build') {
  plugins.push(new UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }))
  outputFile = `${LIBRARY_NAME}.min.js`
} else {
  outputFile = `${LIBRARY_NAME}.js`
}

const config = {
  entry: __dirname + './src/index.js',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: outputFile,
    library: 'Fuse',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /(\.js)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/
    }]
  },
  plugins: plugins
}

module.exports = config
```

**When I browse the page look this**

[image: Browser shows]

after i npm run build it look like this..

[image: after npm run build]

Comment: the error message you are getting `missing build script` is because you haven't added `"scripts": {
        ...
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },` 
try adding this line and then retry

Comment: got still error. i will post the image..

Comment: try running `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install`

Comment: so i need to remove the node_module folder to my project? then run the npm install?

Comment: yes try it and let me know

Comment: ok i try it sec i install npm

Comment: @Goldy already done. do i need to start again the npm run build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185033/discussion-between-devge-and-goldy).

Answer (score 1):

`npm run build`
is missed in the script in `package.json`.
If you want you deploy `npm run prod`.
Or you can run `npm run watch` to see for code changes in real time, but it's good to use on local developement.
If you are working on laravel mix project, you need to set your apache config.

open file`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and then
write your own root directory path

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/<your directory>/public
```

Next, change you .htacces file : open up `/var/www/mmc1/public/.htaccess` 
write the following at the top

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Now, we  need to make your server recognize the .htaccess configuration
Go to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and change 
`AllowOverride None` into `AllowOverride All`

```
<Directory /var/www/<your dir>/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

On your terminal,

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`  //rewrite module enable

`sudo service restart apache2` //restart your server

And it would be work well...