# Now that I've created my react application in the IDE, how do I get it to work from the command line outside of the IDE

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, production

"I have finished developing a react app and I used create-react-app to create the web application.what are the steps that I should take to make the app into production?  I want to host this application in an Apache server.How can I bundle my app using webpack?

Comment: well here's an article on the same by the create-react-app team: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/production-build#docsNav

Comment: So is it enough to run npm run build? no need to write a script to run my application? @DakshMiglani

Comment: yes, `npm run build` will create a production-ready build in a folder named `dist` which you can then serve using an http-server, like nginx / caddy / etc.

Comment: your updated questions seems like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461403/6792646

Comment: I saw that question and couldn't understand.so should I run npm run production command as well?could you please elaborate the answer? @DakshMiglani

Comment: just run `npm run build`, it'll bundle your code and save it in the `dist/` directory. once you're done with that, just copy the files from dist to the web directory of your apache server, and it should serve.

Comment: further more, here's create-react-app's guide on deployment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the command npm run build and take the content in the build folder and deploy it on the server.